# What does it mean by"A preposition govern the nouns or noun-equivalents that follow them."?

Tags: prepositions

(Preposition)They are said **to govern** the nouns.

I want to know in details what it means??

Comment: Please cite your source.

Comment: Perhaps from [Agoi (2003) verified that prepositions are used to
explain the link of noun or noun equivalents which it governs.](https://core.ac.uk/download/pdf/234693375.pdf) Not great English, that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Google has this definition for *govern* under the *Grammar* tab:

> verb
> 2. GRAMMAR
> (of a word) require that (another word or group of words) be in a particular case.

Your example

> (Preposition)They are said to govern the nouns.

means prepositions require that the words or groups of words following them are to be in a particular case.

Prepositions are normally followed by nouns of the object case.  Exceptions are the first prepositions in constructions with double prepositions, like **up to** and **out of**; or in constructions with double possessives, like "a book of his", as what @FumbleFingers commented.

Comment: For example (**of** - possessive case) *a book **of his***, (**by** - objective case) *a book **by him***.

Comment: This question might be about case government specifically, or not, depending on context.    (See https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Government_(linguistics) ).  So, I've asked OP for a clarification.